# Delete cookie on a different sub-domain, or with non-specific TLD

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Say I have a domain `www.widgets.com`

My app was live for a while, with a web.config that explictly set the cookie domain to `.widgets.com` :

```
<httpCookies domain=".widgets.com" requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

Since then, the domain has been removed from the web.config, which means that the cookie domain will include the TLD (`www.widgets.com`) :

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

But.. users's still have cookies set for `.widgets.com`, and I want to remove them (they cause issues). If I try to set new cookies that are expired, they will only work for the `www.widgets.com` domain.

is there a way to remove cookies that were previously set for `.widgets.com` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Such response :)

Ok, here's how I did it.

I created a folder in my app, with it's own web.config, that set's the cookie domain back to `.widgets.com`. I then wrote some simple code that iterates all the cookies that I have, and sets the expiry to yesterday. Because of the web.config, this clears down all the cookies in the old domain setting.

Simples :)